# SQL: How to find null values between different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

From a list of companies which their connected stores do not have employment values >0 in more than one country, I want to retrieve the ids that have null employment values in countries other than the country with the employment. 
In the case below I want to retrieve only the id A.
This is a oracle database.

**The table structure**

Company

```
| id    | store | country| employment
---------------------------------
|A  | 1     |   US      |   0           |
---------------------------------
|A  | 2     |   US      | 9         |
---------------------------------
|A  | 3     | DE        | null      |
---------------------------------
|B  | 4     | US        | 0         |
---------------------------------
|B  | 5     | DE        | null      |
---------------------------------
|B  | 6     | DE        | 4         |
---------------------------------
|B  | 7     | DE        | 4         |
---------------------------------
```

*Forgive me i didnt know how to present the table structure in better format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct id
from company c
group by id, country
having count(employment) <> count(*) and  -- there is at least one NULL value
       count(employment) > 0 ;  -- there is at least one not NULL value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I seems to be working when there are only 2 countries but not with more. e.g it returned both following cases:
|C  | 10    | AT       | 0     
|C  |11     | CZ       | 1     
|C  | 12    | CZ      | null  
|C  | 13    | SK      | null   
|D  | 14    | AT       | 0     
|D  |15     | CZ       | 1      
|D  | 16    | CZ       | null